# Rufus unable to download idlinux.sys and idlinux.bss, any alternate option/fixes?

Tags: windows-7, bootable-media

I am currently trying to install linux but i have this issue of syslinux of diff vers. In the iso. For some reason rufus fails to download the files. Is there any way i can download the files manually and place it in the application directory or whatever it is, so i can install my bootable disk? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which distro of Linux and which version exactly?

Comment: Im trying Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Although i am trying with unetbootin

Comment: As far as I remember Rufus doesn't need any extra files for Ubuntu 18.04. Are you using an up to date version of Rufus? Are you using ISO mode or dd mode?

Comment: Iso mode, and Rufus of

Comment: Rufus Is updated*

Comment: On a side note, i am trying to use ubuntu gamepack, maybe thats the issue

Comment: Try the dd mode, it shouldn't have any external dependencies.

Comment: @gronostaj do you have any recc guide on how to use dd mode?

Comment: Rufus should ask you which mode you want to use each time, at least that's what it does for regular Ubuntu ISOs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For some reason rufus fails to download the files.

Considering that you mention that you are running Rufus on Windows 7, I'm going to go on a limb and assume that, if you open the Rufus log <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> you also see the following:

```
Unable to send request: This system's SSL library is too old to be able to access this website.
```

This message means exactly what it says: If you are seeing this, you are missing critical Windows security updates, that are required to be able to access sites like GitHub/AWS (which is where Rufus stores the downloadable content) in SSL mode.

Please bear in mind that it's not because browsers like Chrome or Firefox can access these sites (because they contain their **own, custom version** of an SSL library) that applications that rely on Windows APIs (which use a different, native version of the SSL library) can.

However, an up to date Windows 7 system should have native SSL libraries that are able to access GitHub using the newer, more secure, SSL protocols (which is really the root of the issue: old versions of the Windows 7 SSL library use an obsolete/insecure version of SSL, that GitHub doesn't allow, and therefore needs to be be updated). So, if you are getting that message, it means that your Windows 7 system is probably not up to date.

You therefore have two options:

1. (preferred) Make sure your Windows 7 system is fully updated before you attempt to use applications that connect to the internet
2. Try [this workaround](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/Usage-Notes#Where_to_manually_copy_the_SyslinuxGRUB_files_if_Rufus_cant_download_them).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I did download the syslinux files manually and was able to install the usb bootable device, but theres still some issue of me not being able to boot into the ubuntu install. My windows is upto date. Btw is it possible my linux version is corrupt?

Answer (score -1):

try the link

https://github.com/pbatard/rufus-web/tree/gh-pages/files

for downloading ldlinux.bss and ldlinux.sys files

Comment: This answer here must contain all of the information necessary in itself. It should not be necessary to follow a link to understand the solution. Please edit your answer to add the required information.